# Find empty files in a directory by using 'find' module

Tags: ansible

I need to find empty files (files with '0' size) that has a pattern in their title inside a directory and delete them. It's pretty basic to do that with a Bash command, as you can add an `-empty` or `-size 0` argument to your `find` command. Then, remove them with a `-delete` argument or pipe it to `xargs`. I basically wanted to do what the command below is doing, but with Ansible's built-in *find module*.

```
find /etc/apparmor.d/libvirt/ -type f -name 'libvirt-*' -empty -delete
```

I thought it would look something like the following,

```yaml
---
- name: Remove empty files from /etc/apparmor.d/libvirt/
  find:
    paths: "/etc/apparmor.d/libvirt"
    patterns: "libvirt-*"
    size: 0
  register: empty_files
- name: Remove empty files
  file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ empty_files.files }}"
  when: empty_files.matched != 0
.
.
.
```

Apparently, `size: 0` doesn't work the way I expect it to work in Ansible. According to the [`ansible.builtin.find module` documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html), size parameter works this way.

> Select files whose size is equal to or greater than the specified size.
>
> Use a negative size to find files equal to or less than the specified size.
>
> Unqualified values are in bytes but b, k, m, g, and t can be appended to specify bytes, kilobytes, megabytes, gigabytes, and terabytes, respectively.
>
> Size is not evaluated for directories.

Am I reading it wrong or is there really not a way to find empty files via find module? I tried `-0` but no luck. Also couldn't find any solid similar case online. I've been suggested to just use the shell module and run the command directly, but then I won't be able to benefit from the rich data from the *find module* and write conditionals according to the output, and also *I want this to work*.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the module. I have the same understanding as you from reading the documentation: `size: "-0"` as a param should return files with a size of 0 (i.e. lower of equal to 0) but does return all files instead as you reported.

I propose the following workaround which should still be quite performant:

- select files with size lower or equal to 1 byte
- further reduce the result to files where size is 0

Here is the playbook I used and ran against a set of crafted files for my test (`file[1-2].txt` empty and `file[3-4].txt` with content)

```yaml
---
- name: Delete empty files in a directory
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    my_dir: "{{ playbook_dir}}/files"
    my_empty_files: "{{ find_1B.files | selectattr('size', '==', 0) }}"

  tasks:
    - name: find files in dir
      ansible.builtin.find:
        paths:
          - "{{ my_dir }}"
        patterns:
          - "file[0-9]{1}.txt"
        use_regex: true
        size: "-1"
      register: find_1B

    - name: Delete empty files
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        state: absent
      loop: "{{ my_empty_files }}"
```

Result:

```
$ ansible-playbook delete_empty.yml

PLAY [Delete empty files in a directory] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [find files in dir] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Delete empty files] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/tmp/toto/files/file1.txt', 'mode': '0644', 'isdir': False, 'ischr': False, 'isblk': False, 'isreg': True, 'isfifo': False, 'islnk': False, 'issock': False, 'uid': 1026, 'gid': 100, 'size': 0, 'inode': 595900, 'dev': 27, 'nlink': 1, 'atime': 1679494676.0987034, 'mtime': 1679494593.5703, 'ctime': 1679494593.5703, 'gr_name': 'users', 'pw_name': 'olcla', 'wusr': True, 'rusr': True, 'xusr': False, 'wgrp': False, 'rgrp': True, 'xgrp': False, 'woth': False, 'roth': True, 'xoth': False, 'isuid': False, 'isgid': False})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/tmp/toto/files/file2.txt', 'mode': '0644', 'isdir': False, 'ischr': False, 'isblk': False, 'isreg': True, 'isfifo': False, 'islnk': False, 'issock': False, 'uid': 1026, 'gid': 100, 'size': 0, 'inode': 595184, 'dev': 27, 'nlink': 1, 'atime': 1679494676.0987034, 'mtime': 1679494599.086327, 'ctime': 1679494599.086327, 'gr_name': 'users', 'pw_name': 'olcla', 'wusr': True, 'rusr': True, 'xusr': False, 'wgrp': False, 'rgrp': True, 'xgrp': False, 'woth': False, 'roth': True, 'xoth': False, 'isuid': False, 'isgid': False})

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

If you run the same playbook again, there are no more empty files and the delete task returns:

```
TASK [Delete empty files] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]
```

Comment: This is an elegant workaround. Much appreciated, @Zeitounator . I've also been trying to prevent the playbook from running subsequent tasks, if there isn't any empty file in the directory. Since I can't use `when: empty_files.matched != 0` anymore (Filtered variable *my_empty_files* is a list of dictionaries.), I came up with `when: empty_files | length != 0`. To the all future folks.

Comment: if there are no empty files `my_empty_files` will be an empty list and the task will have no items to loop on. There is no need for a when clause.

Comment: Yes, no issues with the file removal task. Much appreciated. I meant for the subsequent tasks that will come after the file removal task. For example, if there were some empty files found, I had to restart some services in my case. Just mentioned it as a side note.

Comment: Have the task notify a handler. Done.